# How to call external server page with PHP that includes JS?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, httprequest

There is a website which includes a JS code. Normally, when the page is opened by a user this JS code starts manually and provides a link about 10 seconds.
I am trying to catch this link. In PHP, I call this page with file_get_contents function, however as you predict link is not there.

Is there any way to make a HTTP request to this page and wait until javascript code started. Or can I invoke this JS function by using JQuery maybe?

If the question is not clear, I can provide more details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use the sleep() function in PHP to wait for 10 seconds for the JS to execute.

Comment: do I need to call sleep() after file_get_contents?

Comment: That won't help, you'll get the contents as text, so no JS execution will be started, thus `sleep` is useless. If the link is added to the page with JS you'll have to implement some other approach, e.g. using embedded browser. That's not possible in PHP as far as I know, but C#, Java, C++, Delphi have such browsers for sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to include and call a JavaScript function from a PHP script? And how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381210/is-it-possible-to-include-and-call-a-javascript-function-from-a-php-script-and-h)

Comment: you mentioned that the JS code starts manually. Then how are you using the file_get_content function for that?

Comment: Actually I am not interested in calling the function. The page already handles JS side. What I want is emulating a normal browser until JS done its job and then get the html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into the javascript on the page and reverse-engineer how the link is dynamically generated. Then you can use regex to extract that info from the string returned by file_get_contents.

I can probably help you on the reverse-engineering if you can provide extra information on the page in question (or similar).

UPDATE:
After some reversing, I found that the mp3 ripper site uses 2 api's: one to push a video to get processed, and one to poke at the current status.

First api:

```
http://www.youtube-mp3.org/api/pushItem/?item=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DXXXXXXXX&xy=trve
```

Second api:

```
http://www.youtube-mp3.org/api/itemInfo/?video_id=XXXXXXXX&adloc=
```

XXXXXXXX is the youtube video id. The 2nd api returns JSONP where the padding is a variable assignment (info = {...};). In the json, there's a "h" member that returns a long hash which can be used to ultimately construct the mp3 download file link.

But to be a bit ethical, may I suggest looking into another approach (if allowed by your hosting environment)? You can use FFmpeg to convert the video on your own. There's a wrapper class here: [YouTube-to-MP3 conversion class](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=205066)

Comment: The web site I'm talking about is [this](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/)
If I call this webpage by providing youtube video id, it generates the result for example try [this](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/?c#v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ)
I have video id in my php, and I want to call this page in background and return the mp3 link.

Comment: Do you want to fetch the link to the actual mp3 file, or the "Direct Link" the website provides after you click on "Link this mp3"?

Comment: Wow! I am amazed with your reverse engineering. You are right about the ethical issue too. I will also try to implement your suggestion. But probably this conversion needs a large bandwidth.
I am also wonder how you do reversing? I have just spend hours for understanding the mechanism. Is there any way to improve my reverse engineering, or is it just experience?

Comment: =D. All you need is a browser to do the reversing. In this case I used Chrome's Network tab in the inspector to track the background Ajax calls. So I guess to get good at it, you'd want to know javascript better and know how to use a browser's debugging features. Experience wise, I've been designing websites since 2002. So that helps too.

Comment: @Dave hey, the first api normally would start a conversion if the requested video isn't cached on their servers, but since a week or two it has stopped working. It won't start a conversion. So the second api only returns the JSON data if the video is cahced on their servers, and if not it returns nil, because you can't start a new conversion. Did the URL of the first api change or what, please check that, heres my question on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763141/youtube-mp3-org-api-not-working-properly-only-downloads-cached-videos

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is executed on the client and needs an interpreter to execute it. Your PHP server executing HTTP request calls won't interpret any javascript, it will simply just retrieve the HTML.

You could use some software like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to make the request and execute the javascript, and then see if you can extract the link after it has finished executing. This will depend on how much access you have to the server you are executing your PHP on.

Or you could study the JS files used by the website you are targeting, determine how it is requesting that link and see if you can just get it directly yourself. Bear in mind you are directly working around how the site is intended to work, so this isn't going to be a particularly elegant solution and a single change in their JS could cause your application to fail. This is fair enough as they might have this very process in place to stop people from being able to harvest the links in the manner you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` only fetches the HTML source of the URL requested, it does not execute the javascript code for you nor simulates the dom with all it's events.

The short answer would be, that this can not be easily done. One thing you could do is to parse the source and look for the link in there, like [Dave suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566522/how-to-call-external-server-page-with-php-that-includes-js/7566718#7566718).